# Graphic editor - How do I use the graphic editor correctly?

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I don't know how to use the graphic editor and I need help, I want to get the result of the video but so far without success

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M43UvNCNKko

This is a seven-headed dragon, I would like some advice
help
from a professional who knows how to do this, and make something smooth or similar to the video I sent

[image]

[image]

My friends have explained a lot to me, but I can't understand because they speak in a very technical way.
if you can also help me solve this, it's better to explain it without these difficult words I don't understand, a metaphor or a fun way to explain it.

yes, i already went to the bottom of the internet to see  videos i didn't understand.

When I try it myself, the movements get weird and locked, with sudden movements of one way and then it quickly changes to another shape, looking like a constant or linear

What do I do? I really want to achieve the result of the video, or more than that.

To summarize what I'm trying to do

what i tried to do

To make realistic moves like I expected to do, I tried going to the graph editor and moving the curves with G + Y, moving from top to bottom, something like that, I would move it in a way that suits me and skip some frames

I'm also trying to use I, create a new frame to see if this can help me, even with SHIFT + S, in Flatten Handles. Hitting V and going to vector, but I always end up in the same hole.

With very strange movements, fast and tasteless.

In other words, I just climb the curves and tweak them in a way that I think is cool.

[image]

The goal of everything was just to make good movement and similar to the video.

Here the file so you can better analyze my problem.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/77wdgutxr0uzzue/GRAPH.blend/file

Comment: Please [share your own](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/227554/edit) results with the community, what exactly you have tried, and how it is not working compared to the results you wish to achieve. See the [tour] and [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to better understand how to get the most out of this site and receive better answers.

Comment: i tried to do something soft
It looks like realistic and dynamic motion like in the video

I will try to be as detailed as possible
the problem i have is that it gets too fast, most of the time and it gets weird, sudden movements

I'm sorry, I'm sure I won't be able to explain it in the same way, so I'll give you the file

https://www.mediafire.com/file/77wdgutxr0uzzue/GRAPH.blend/file

And, I will follow the advice, next time I will check.

Comment: please try to add all new information as an [edit] rather than in the comments, that way other users will see it in the body of your question. Comments are considered to be temporary and disposable information that many users do not bother reading.

Comment: Okay, I've already done that. Do I have to do something else, or is it okay?

Comment: As a general rule, I would say that you want to begin your animations with the Dope Sheet, not the Graph Editor. Once you get the basic timing blocked out in the Dope Sheet, you can go into the Graph Editor to fine tune it. Essentially, I think of the Graph Editor as an "easing in/easing out" editor. Usually, unless easing behavior is what I specifically want to edit, I stay in the Dope Sheet.